# Total Result, (Sum or Subtract some Value) according to Flag Column Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, consolidation

I'm newbie in SQL Developer.

[image]

I have a query result like the above image.

I want to know how to sum all values with `Flag = 1` and to subtract all the values With `Flag = 2` in order to obtain a total result?

Comment: Use SQL - see answers below. OR, you can right-click, export to Excel (XLSX), and then use your Excel powers there. SQL is quite powerful though and I hope you give it a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help of `DECODE`, here's how:

```
SQL> with test (value, flag) as
  2    (select 100, 2 from dual union  -- sum of flag 2 values = 600
  3     select 200, 2 from dual union
  4     select 300, 2 from dual union
  5     --
  6     select 700, 1 from dual union  -- sum of flag 1 values = 1500
  7     select 800, 1 from dual
  8    )
  9  select sum(decode(flag, 1, value, 0)) sum_1,
 10         sum(decode(flag, 2, value, 0)) sum_2,
 11         --
 12         sum(decode(flag, 1, value, 0)) - sum(decode(flag, 2, value, 0)) result
 13  from test;

     SUM_1      SUM_2     RESULT
---------- ---------- ----------
      1500        600        900

SQL>
```

Comment: CASE is just another flavor of DECODE; I'm glad you made it